# arcgis.features line features failing to buffer

Tags: buffer, arcgis-python-api

I'm trying to write a script that buffers a line dataset.

I'm able to successfully buffer a single polygon but, when I try and buffer my three lines, the code fails.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import Polygon, Geometry, Polyline, Point, union
from arcgis.geometry.filters import intersects, contains, overlaps, crosses, touches, within
from arcgis.geometry.filters import envelope_intersects, index_intersects
from arcgis.geocoding import geocode
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
from arcgis.features import summarize_data
import re
import json

class lib:
    def buildPolygons():
        lines = '''[
                    {"paths": [[[378252.4268, 4900479.5447], [378191.1202, 4900521.3696]]], 
                    "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918}, 
                    "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 1}}, 
                    {"paths": [[[371360.6891, 4900238.783], [371360.3857, 4900245.9489]]], 
                    "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918}, "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 2}}, 
                    {"paths": [[[383215.9289, 4899951.9734], [383218.4808, 4899951.5379], [383337.8548, 4899969.4266]]], 
                    "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918}, 
                    "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 3}}
                    ]
                    '''
        polys = '''{"rings": [[[377384.56048584, 4904859.7612915], [377384.56048584, 4904133.47869873],
                    [376864.653076172, 4904125.54107666], [376778.717895508, 4903891.43951416],
                    [376487.62109375, 4903958.85327148], [377039.278503418, 4904851.82391357],
                    [377384.56048584, 4904859.7612915]]],
                    "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918},
                    "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 1}}
                    '''

        polysJson = Polygon(polys)

        linesJson = Polyline(lines)
        print(linesJson)
        #   output:
        #   {'x':
        #   {'paths': [[[378252.4268, 4900479.5447], [378191.1202, 4900521.3696]]],
        #   'spatialReference': {'wkid': 26918, 'latestWkid': 26918},
        #   'attributes': {'OBJECTID': 1}}, 'y':
        #   {'paths': [[[371360.6891, 4900238.783], [371360.3857, 4900245.9489]]],
        #   'spatialReference': {'wkid': 26918, 'latestWkid': 26918},
        #   'attributes': {'OBJECTID': 2}},
        #   'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}}
        

        polyBuffer = polysJson.buffer(distance=1)
        print('buffered the polygons!')

        # Code fails here. I'm not sure why
        lineBuffer = linesJson.buffer(distance=1)
        print('buffered the lines!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lib.buildPolygons()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polyline() accepts one line at a time and not an array of lines. You could do something like this.

```
lines = [
                '''{"paths": [[[378252.4268, 4900479.5447], [378191.1202, 4900521.3696]]], 
                "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918}, 
                "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 1}}''', 
                '''{"paths": [[[371360.6891, 4900238.783], [371360.3857, 4900245.9489]]], 
                "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918}, "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 2}}''', 
                '''{"paths": [[[383215.9289, 4899951.9734], [383218.4808, 4899951.5379], [383337.8548, 4899969.4266]]], 
                "spatialReference": {"wkid": 26918, "latestWkid": 26918}, 
                "attributes": {"OBJECTID": 3}}'''
                ]
```

Then iterate for each line.

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    linesJson = Polyline(line)
    print(linesJson)
    lineBuffer = linesJson.buffer(distance=1)
    print('buffered the lines!')
```